# SQL Server - Get First rows matching date criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this:

```
 ID   DateValue       Amount
 -----------------------------
 1    2017/08/09      217 
 1    2017/08/08      204    
 1    2017/08/07      322    
 2    2017/08/09      1543    
 2    2017/08/08      1285    
 3    2017/08/09      12 
 4    2017/08/09      347
```

I only want to obtain the first rows for the most recent "DateValue" value. Like this:

```
 ID   DateValue       Amount
 -----------------------------
 1    2017/08/09      217 
 2    2017/08/09      1543    
 3    2017/08/09      12 
 4    2017/08/09      347
```

I thought of using the "MAX" method like this:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DateValue), MAX(Amount) FROM [dbo].[MyTable] GROUP BY Id
```

But for the ID 1, I get 322 while I should have 217 (the most recent value)

Is there a simple way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: `Select * from table where dateValue = '2017/08/09'`?  I gotta be missing something.  or maybe your sample data and expected results don't show the problem you're having.

Comment: The date is not always the same for each id. Sometimes the most recent date can be earlier for a singular id. I can't select rows with a precise date, it has to be the most recent one regardless the id.

Comment: Re: "I should have 217." When you select the maximum value from a `group` that's what you get. When you select several maxima from a group you will get the maximum for each of the columns (or expressions) within the group. Since 322 is the maximum `Amount` for `Id` 1, that's what you get. The maximum `DateValue` for that group is `2017/08/09` (whatever that means). There is no reason to expect them to come from the same row within the group. PSA: [ISO date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **WITH TIES** clause.

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Id Order By DateValue Desc)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: is it me or would a `Select * from table where dateValue = '2017/08/09'` do this as well?

Comment: @xQbert Now that you mention it... With this sample YES.  Talk about an Eagle  Eye !

Comment: It didn't make sense to me to have the same date on the same id with different amounts... so then I went hu?

Answer (score 0):

This also work ,

```
  select ID,DateValue,Amount from 
(select ID,DateValue,Amount,ROW_NUMBER() over
 (partition by ID order by DateValue Desc)  RowNumber  
from [dbo].[MyTable]) x
where RowNumber=1
```